# Problems starting intent

Tags: android, android-intent

hello i have been searching for an answer on the web, but i can't find anything... i am pretty sure i'm doing everything right here so it could be a problem because i am using an emulator?
Here is my code... I've also added the other activity to the manifest file...

```
package com.example.help;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class GlavniIzbornik extends Activity {

Button settings;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    settings = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bttnSettings);

    settings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent settings = new Intent(GlavniIzbornik.this,TounamentSettings.class);
            GlavniIzbornik.this.startActivity(settings);
        }

    });
}
```

}

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tournamentpro"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tournamentpro.GlavniIzbornik"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.tournamentpro.TournamentSettings" ></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: try removing `GlavniIzbornik.this.` so you just have `startActivity(settings);` left. Also what exactly is the problem that you are seeing? Does the app force close? If so look in your logcat for an exception. Copy the red text and add it to your question so we can help.

Comment: @FoamyGuy
i've tried it without the GlavniIzbornik.this. part, the app crashes when i press the button i've made...
logcat says this:
http://pastebin.com/1jQw5Dnb

Comment: From your stacktrace it looks like our Activity is not declared in your manifest. Edit your question and post your manifest code. Perhaps try cleaning your project.

Comment: i have the activity in my manifest... i don't know why it says that...

Comment: you have declared TournamentSettings but your class name is TounamentSettings

Comment: omg... damn typos... thank you so much... i was going crazy here :)

Answer (score 1):

All looks good. Rember that

1. TounamentSettings has to `extends Activity`
2. TounamentSettings has to be declared inside `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: I know it looks good, that's why i don't understand why it's not working... i have: <activity android:name="com.example.tournamentpro.TournamentSettings" ></activity> in my manifest

Comment: you have declared TournamentSettings but your class name is TounamentSettings